# Android wear: Is there a way to detect when the watch enters and exits ambient mode even if you're not in the app?

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect when the watch enters and exits ambient mode even if you're not in the app?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

No its not possible , because once wearable activity destroys, ambient callback also finished.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on